# Google Sheets Formula Query

Tags: google-sheets

I've tried a couple of formulae but none seem to work. I'm trying to include a formula which calculates average miles required based on mileage YTD to make a goal of 2017 miles in 2017.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Alan

Comment: which formulas did you try?

Comment: Is that average miles per day/week/month? Could you give a sample calculation with expected result?

Comment: It's average per day. So 2017 Miles a day Less 5 Miles on day 1 would leave 5.5 approx per day to stay on target to make goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
=(Target-Current)/(EndDate-Date)
```

(filling in your cell references as required - I have used named ranges) so for your example you would get (2017-5)/(date(2017,12,31)-date(2017,1,1)) which gives 5.5.

So if you didn't want to bother with named ranges, the equivalent would be

```
($F$2-C2)/$E$2-A2)
```

and as you dragged it down the A2 and C2 would change but the $F$2 and $E$2 would stay fixed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a go

Comment: It works. Thank you. Question. Can I drag and drop a copy of formula and it will work the date out itself? Or does each date need to be input manually?

Comment: If you did some miles every day then you could just fill in every date for the whole year by dragging the bottom right corner of the date cell down and using fill series, but if you had a lot of gaps then it would probably mean filling them in as you went along (unless you kept to some ort of fixed pattern like weekdays/weekends only).

Comment: Some days I'm 5 miles and others I'm 2/3 miles. So it does vary.

Comment: I can do auto fill but that doesn't let it run in order. All it does is repeat the pattern on the first 2?

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: I'll put a screenshot of how I imagine it to be for the first two or three weeks - hope that helps.

Comment: Cheers. I'm not a level 10 or something so can't post screenshots or pics.